# Install Odoo from sourcce: Error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I am using source code https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/aa0554d224337e1d966479a351a3ed059d297765

on Windows 10, Python version

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

I catch error

[image]

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5g8ghcb\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

- From [Windows Source Install](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html#source-install)

  > Warning
  >
  > Some dependencies cannot be installed through pip and require to be installed manually.
  >   In particular:
  >
  > - `psycopg` must be installed with
  >     [this  installer](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).
  > - `wkhtmltopdf` must be installed in version 0.12.5
  >     for it to support headers and footers. See our
  >     wiki for more details on the
  >      various versions.
- As the error message suggest to you:

  > If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
  >       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
- The [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/2.8.4/#files) package for Python 3.8 is released and you can
  install it with pip:

  ```
  pip install psycopg2
  ```
- If you want to install psycopg2 from source, refer to the [official
  docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html).